# Automated fsck (with init 1/init 5) on a FreeBSD machine?

Tags: sh, freebsd, init, fsck

I'm looking to automated fsck on my FreeBSD server. I have an idea how to do this, but because it's running pretty powerful commands, I'd like some more eyes on it before I set it to run.

Step 1. Cron job.
My cron will look something like this: `0 17 * * 0 myfsckscript.sh > /usr/local/var/log/fscklog/$(date).log`, to run at 5PM every sunday. It will be run from root's crontab, because what I'm doing requires root permissions.

The script goes something like this:

```
init 1 # Run single-user mode, so fsck can run correctly
fsck -y # Run fsck
fsck -y # Run again, to clean up. Makes my machine act better
init 5 # bring it back up.
```

My main concerns follow:

- Does running this pose any substantial dangers I should know about?
- Are there any errors in my script?
- Anything I should add?
- Did I actually get it right?

I'm sorry this is mostly a confirmation question, but with my level of skill with sh I'm not comfortable setting this to run without someone more experienced taking a look first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just add this to [/etc/rc.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?rc.conf(5)):

```
fsck_y_enable="YES"
background_fsck="NO"
```

Basically, means to run `fsck -y` and don't try to run in background, so depending on the size of your disks, this could take a while to finish.

Comment: This looks like it's perfect for me; I'll schedule a weekly reboot and it should keep things running smoothly.

Just so I'm 100% clear, this will run `fsck -y` every time I boot into multi-user mode?

Comment: why would you like to reboot the server, there is no need to so,  `fsck_y_enable` will execute `fsck -y` on boot time but only if needed